# .Net How should I Match string

Tags: c#, .net

If I have such a string

```
string str = "aaa{bbb}cc{ddd}[number]";
string number = "12";


foreach (var item in str )
{
    Console.WriteLine(item+"\r\n");
}
```

How do i get the output

```
a
a
a
bbb
c
c
ddd
12
```

This str may have different sequence lengths

like `string str = "{bbb}aaa[number]cc{ddd}";`

What i want to do is ，If str does not have any {} [] brackets

```
string str = "aaabbbccc";
```

He will output

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

If there are {} brackets

```
string str = "aaa{bbb}";
```

Will output

```
a
a
a
bbb
```

If there are [] brackets

```
string str = "aaa{bbb}[ccc]";
string replaceStr = "This is replaceStr";
```

He will be replaced with replaceStr, then the output string[] is

```
a
a
a
bbb
This is replaceStr
```

What I mean is this, my English is not very good, sorry for the trouble you caused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the expected format of your input string? What are the rules for parsing?

Comment: If there is no {} outside the string, it will be split into single characters，If there is {} outside the string, it will not be split into single characters.If there is [] outside the string, replace the content with a string

Comment: So letters enclosed by `{}` will be grouped together and anything enclosed within `[]` will be replaced by the value of a scoped variable?

Comment: is `[number]` the only possible token to be replaced or could you have others `[someOtherVar]{bbb}[yetAnother]`

Comment: @Jamiec yes ！it have

Comment: @phuzi Yes, what you mean is what I mean

Comment: Can you give us some more context for this problem? Where does this string come from?

Comment: Aaaah 20 minutes to write up a good answer and its closed before I can post it. Have the dotnetfiddle - its all I can do! https://dotnetfiddle.net/JpYNHn @closevotes - it's _completely_ clear what this OP is trying to do!

Comment: @Jamiec oh Think you ,This seems to be what I want, I will test it in about eight hours, because my time here is already one o'clock in the morning

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a custom parsing job to me..

```
var r = new Regex(@"\b(?=[{[])|[}\]]");
var t = r.Split("aaaa{bbb}ccc{ddd}[number]");
var numbers = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "[number", "12" } };

var z = new List<string>();
foreach (var u in t)
{
    if (u.Length == 0) continue;
    else if (u.StartsWith("[") && numbers.TryGetValue(u, out var v)) z.Add(v);
    else if (u.StartsWith("{")) z.Add(u[1..]);
    else z.AddRange(u[1..].Select(c => c.ToString()));
}
```

If we use a regex to break it up into interesting parts, we get (from the regex split)

```
aaa
{bbb
cc
{ddd
[number
//empty string
```

Then we can take a look at the first char - if it's a `[` do the substitute, if it's a `{` add it verbatim (without the `{`), and otherwise, chip it into its constituent chars

What do you want to do if the string contains `[non_existent]` (a placeholder you have no replacement for) ?